# Find $y$-Lipschitz constant

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

$$f(x,y)=x^3e^{-xy^2}, 0\leq x\leq a, y\in \mathbb R, a>0$$

I need to find $K>0$ such that $$|f(x,y_1)-f(x, y_2)|\leq K|y_1-y_2|$$ for all $0\leq x\leq a$ and $y_1,y_2\in \mathbb R$

I did this $$|x^3e^{-xy_1^2}-x^3e^{-xy_2^2}|=x^3|e^{-xy_1^2}-e^{-xy_2^2}|\leq a^3|e^{-xy_1^2}-e^{-xy_2^2}|$$

now I don't know what to do.

Comment: You've found the [Hölder-$0$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder_condition) norm of $f$, but the Lipschitz norm is the Hölder-$1$ norm of $f$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to find a Lipschitz constant of $x \mapsto \mathrm{e}^{-x}$, $x \ge 0$. Hint: Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Then, you can use this in your Lipschitz estimate.

Answer (score 1):

Better to find $\frac{df}{dy}$, then you will get either $2a^3$  or $2a^4$.

Comment: What is your reasoning? Actually, you get $a^{7/2}\sqrt{2/e}$.

Comment: Dear Robjohn my argument is correct. I have posted detailed argument you can see below if you have still any doubt you can contact me. Also, You can refer text 'Theory of ordinary differential equations' "coddington ". It's an exercise problem.

Comment: Well, it was uncertain whether you were saying that the constant is $\max(2a^3,2a^4)$ or $\min(2a^3,2a^4)$. Your answer below clarifies that you meant $\max(2a^3,2a^4)$, which is correct. However, $a^{7/2}\sqrt{2/e}$ is tighter (always smaller) than $\max(2a^3,2a^4)$.

Answer (score 1):

Lipschitz constant Lipschitz constant Lipschitz constant Lipschitz constant
[image: Lipschitz constant]

Comment: You should really put these details in your other answer and it would help if you could type this in LaTeX so that others can edit and/or quote portions of your answer. I've recommended this for deletion as it has no upvotes and you have another answer on this thread.

Answer (score 0):

I'll go on from where you stopped at $ a^3|e^{-xy_1^2}-e^{-xy_2^2}|$. Let's note that $ 0 \leq e^{-xy_1^2}\leq 1$ because this is a monotone decreasing function of $x$, and therefore, it receives a maximum when $x=0$, such that:

$ a^3|e^{-xy_1^2}-e^{-xy_2^2}|\leq a^3|1-e^{-xy_2^2}|.$

Let's use the fact that $ e^{-xy_2^2}\geq 0$, to conclude that:

$ a^3|e^{-xy_1^2}-e^{-xy_2^2}|\leq a^3|1-e^{-xy_2^2}|\leq a^3\cdot 1=a^3$

Comment: I'm sorry, I decided to unnaccept because I realised I don't understand why $|f(x,y_1)-f(x,y_2)|\leq a^3$ implies $|f(x,y_1)-f(x,y_2)|\leq a^3\leq K|y_1-y_2|$, for some $K$ which arguably is supposed to be $a^3$.

Answer (score 0):

The [Mean Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) says that the $y$-Lipschitz constant would be
$$
\sup_{\substack{x\in[0,a]\\y\in\mathbb{R}}}\left|\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(x,y)\right|
$$
So we compute
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(x,y)
&=-2x^4ye^{-xy^2}\\
&=-2x^{7/2}x^{1/2}ye^{-xy^2}\\
&=-2x^{7/2}ue^{-u^2}\\
\left|\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(x,y)\right|&\le2a^{7/2}\frac1{\sqrt{2e}}
\end{align}
$$
where we find the maximum of $ue^{-u^2}$ by taking its derivative and solving
$$
(1-2u^2)e^{-u^2}=0
$$
to get $u=1/\sqrt2$. Thus, the maximum of $ue^{-u^2}$ is $1/\sqrt{2e}$.

Therefore,
$$
|f(x,y_1)-f(x, y_2)|\le a^{7/2}\sqrt{2/e}\,|y_1-y_2|
$$